# Reading csv file throwing exception The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object ***

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to read csv file using oledb prover, tried lot much on stack overflow finding the solution but till i stuck on same place. Please check below code what i doing wrong or what i missed there.

```
   OleDbConnectionStringBuilder Builder = new 
   OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
     if (filetype.Equals("csv"))
                {
                    type = ".csv";
                    Builder.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
                    Builder.Add("Extended Properties", 
                    string.Format("Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited;", "No"));
                }


    //folderpath ="D://TestFolder";
                    Builder.DataSource = folderpath ;
                    var dt = new DataTable();
                    string query = string.Empty;
                    if (type.Equals(".xlsx"))
                    {
                        query = "SELECT top 1 * FROM [Sheet1$]";
                    }
                    else if (type.Equals(".csv"))
                    {
                        query = "SELECT top 1 * FROM " + entityItem;
                    }
                    using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection { 
                   ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString })
                    {
                        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand { CommandText 
                    = query, Connection = cn })
                        {
                            if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                            {
                                cn.Close();
                            }
                            cn.Open();
                            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();//Here i m getting error
                            dt.Load(dr);
                        }
                    }
```

//Error = System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'AccountTest.txt'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.'

The question is it is csv file then why in error it is showing txt file

Below is my csv file (AccountTest.csv)

AccountID,AcountName,Phone,AccountNumber

1,nandeshwar,4324353,5325353

Comment: could you please show your `entityItem`? and also add `Builder` class file

Comment: @er-shoaib sorry, it is OleDbConnectionStringBuilder , I have updated code please suggest

Comment: Is that `query = "SELECT top 1 * FROM " + entityItem;` has `entityItem` containing `AccountTest.txt` instead of `AccountTest.csv`? Also you're not specifying data source path to CSV file inside connection string.

Comment: What does the variable `entityItem` hold? What does the variable `query` hold when the exception is thrown. This is fundamental troubleshooting.

Comment: entityItem = AccountTest (without extension), datasource path="D://TestFolder"

Comment: I think `SELECT top 1 * FROM AccountTest` doesn't make sense to read CSV file using JET OLEDB. You should append `.csv` extension after the file name.

Comment: Now it is showing System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Could not find installable ISAM.'

Comment: Anyhow I got solution, and I got data, but there is one issue, numeric fields are not retrieving. do anyone have idea?

Comment: You should ask that question in a new thread.

Comment: I have got same solution, solution was passing number as a string enclosing as "Number"